# How configure log4net for a c# Windows service

Tags: windows-services, log4net

I have a windows service where the app.config file and the log4net.config files are seperate. The logging is not working.

In my app.config file, I have the following in the  section:

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config"/>
```

This works if in the value I specify an absolute path to the log4net.config file.

Do I need to supply an absolute path to the log4net.cong? Both the log4net.config and app.config file are in the same folder as the executable.

any ideas?

Parag

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful ([Moving your Log4Net configuration out of web.config with ASP.NET 2.0 web sites][1].).

Here are the parts that you might be interested:

> Tell the application to configure
> log4net using this config file. There
> are really two spots for this. First,
> the global.asax and second the
> assemblyInfo.cs file. Note, that most
> of the time you will start out with a
> global.asax file with all of the code
> inline. For whatever reason, the only
> way I could get this to work was to
> break the global.asax up to use a
> code-behind and then ass the
> assemblyInfo.cs file.  So it ends up
> looking like this.
>
> global.asax:
> <%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="GlobalAsax" %>
> global.asax.cs (in your App_Code folder):

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class GlobalAsax : HttpApplication
{
    // you may have lots of other code here
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
}
```

> Now that you have your application
> calling log4net's configuration, you
> can set an attribute in your assembly
> info so that log4net knows where to
> look for the configuration file.
> `AssemblyInfo.cs` (in your `App_Code`
> folder):
>
> `[assembly:log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]`

The watch flag tells log4net to keep an

> eye on the configuration file for
> potential changes.  This is helpful if
> you want to change the configuration
> from logging everthing to errors only
> during the middle of your testing.

To make sure that the `log4net.config` is always there, add the log4net.config to the csproject, and set it to `CopyAlways`. It should be presented in the debug folder.

You can use a script to copy everything to a release folder, or if you are using MS setup project, manually add that file into the project. A reference will then be added.
[1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20160928002238/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/bsherwin/archive/2008/02/15/119657.aspx

Comment: i have just managed to do this with information from http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2007/04/log4net-net-logging-tool.html but now I have the problem that the setup porject will not copy across the log4net.config file when the service is installed. How can I get the log4net.config file in my setup project?

Comment: My friend, I'd give you 1000 points if I could. It's Friday night, I wanna go home, and my stupid service was logging if run as a console app, but not when started from the Services panel. And it was the [assembly] attribute that was missing. Thanks.

Comment: I used to use only assembly attribute for console apps, but it looks like windows services need both of the `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` line and assembly attribute.

Comment: First i was like, "THIS IS NOT WHAT WAS ASKED!" Then i was like whoooooa :) Great answer!

Answer (score 14):

For Windows service the current directory is Windows\system32 -- and XmlConfigurator.Configure() uses FileInfo which treats relative paths relative to the current directory. So log4net is looking for its config file in Windows\system32.

XmlConfiguratorAttribute on the other hand uses application's BaseDirectory, this is why it always works.

Alternatively, you can do following before calling XmlConfigurator.Configure() :

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Comment: This was a very useful comment for me!  Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here and this nugget of information about base paths was key. Thanks.

Comment: You save me a lot of time! Thank you!