# log4net configuration for project and unit test in one solution

Tags: c#, windows, unit-testing, service, log4net-configuration

My solution contains a Windows Service application project and a Unit Test project, as shown here:

[image]

---

### -------------------Windows Service application project Setup--------------------

---

**I've setup log4net in my Windows Service application project, as shown below:**

**Step 1)**  I've added the reference to log4net to my Windows Service application project.

**Step 2)**  My app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
    </configSections>

    <log4net>
      <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="log.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message %exception%newline" />
        </layout>
      </appender>
      <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      </root>
    </log4net>

</configuration>
```

**Step 3)**  I've added this the Program.cs main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

namespace MyAppService
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

**Step 4)**  In my classes where I am logging I've added this:

```
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Reader));
```

**Step 5)**  I've added logging statements like this:

```
logger.Info("Data Read Completed Successfully.");
```

---

### -----------------------------Unit Test project Setup----------------------------

---

**I've setup log4net in my Unit Test project, as shown here:**

**Step 1)**  I've added the reference to log4net to my Unit Test project.

**Step 2)**  I've added a app.config file that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
    <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="false" />

      <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="A1" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**Step 3)**  I've added this the ForecastIOTest.cs unit test class:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WeatherAppService;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

namespace WeatherAppTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ForecastIOTest
    {
        private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WeatherController));

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void Configure(TestContext tc)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }
```

**Step 4)**  In my test class where I am logging I've added this:

```
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ForecastIOTest));
```

**Step 5)**  I've added logging statements like this:

```
logger.Info("This is a test.");
```

---

### -------------------------------------Problem------------------------------------

---

**Now, the error that I receive indicates that I have more than one configSections element:  One in the Service app and another in the test app.**

```
log4net:ERROR Exception while reading ConfigurationSettings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element. (C:\Users\pdl\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WeatherAppService\WeatherAppTests\bin\Debug\WeatherAppTests.dll.config line 9)
```

**But if I remove the the configSections from the test app, I receive this error:**

```
log4net:ERROR Exception while reading ConfigurationSettings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section log4net. (C:\Users\pdl\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WeatherAppService\WeatherAppTests\bin\Debug\WeatherAppTests.dll.config line 7)
```

---

### -------------------------------------Question------------------------------------

---

Does anybody know how to set up log4net, so I can run the unit test, which runs the service app and get my log files written to?  Or, given everything I have done, can someone please tell me what is incorrect or incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because, configSection should be the first element after `<Configuration>` in the config file.
`<configuration>
 <configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
 </configSections>`

`<ConfigSections>` element specifies the configuration and handler declaration, so this must be the first child of `<Configuration>`